# Retrieve JSON from page_load method

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, webforms

I have two methods running under page_load: CreateTables() and GetTables(). GetTables() returns a dataset and I would like to retrieve that dataset and populate a table on my webpage.

This is the VB.NET code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    dbConnection = String.Format("Data Source={0}", file)
    CreateTables()
    GetTables()
End Sub
```

How would I retrieve that dataset?

Answer (score 1):

To get `JSON` in a webforms application it's better implement a custom solution rather than use the standard `Page life Cycle`. That way you will control better the way to send an render the JSON wherever you want. You can use HttpHandler Page methods or Web services. I propose using HttpHandlers:

1. Create a custom `HTTPHandler` (*.ashx). Handle your request in the ProcessRequest method. This method must get data from the Request, process it and write a json to the HTTP Response:

   ```
   using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace WebApplication2
    {
       public class JSONHandler : IHttpHandler
       {
          public bool IsReusable
          {
             return false;
          }

          public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
          {
             string name = (string)context.Request["Name"];

             var obj = new { Error = false, Name= name };
             JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(obj);

             context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
             context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
             context.Response.Write(result);
           }
         }
       }
   ```
2. Call this handler using `jQuery.Ajax`. You must target the **.ashx**

   ```
     function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "JSONHandler.ashx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'Name': 'Joseph'},
        success: function(data){
          if(!data.Error){
             var name = data.Name;
             alert(name)
           }
         },
         return false;
       }
   ```

Comment: I'm confused. Do I put the code that was in GetTables() into ProcessRequest() or do I used ProcessRequest() to call GetTables()?

Comment: Put the GetTables() into ProcessRequest().